# Question BackgroundWorker and Open New Page

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

Im using BackgroundWorker to make somes events, like this:

```
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Worker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

inside DoWork, I have:

```
void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        int totalExecucao = 2;
        int count = 0;

        setMensagemText(count++, "Verificando Banco de dados...", totalExecucao);
        VerificaDataBase();

        setMensagemText(count++, "Verificando Configurações Locais", totalExecucao);
        verificaConfiguracaoLocal();


        worker.ReportProgress(100);

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
            mw.Show();
            this.Close();
        }));
```

I have to check "configurações locais", if have no register, I have to open a Page and user need make somes config and save, after that, for end open MainView Form, for check that I using this code:

```
private void verificaConfiguracaoLocal()
    {
        LocalBean localBean = new LocalBean();
        localBean.CarregaModel();


        if (localBean.Model.Id > -1)
        //if(localBean.Model.Id == 0)
        {


            Thread novaNotificacao = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Notify));
            novaNotificacao.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            novaNotificacao.Start();
            worker.CancelAsync();
            void Notify()
            {
                LocalPage lp = new LocalPage();
                Window win2 = new Window();
                win2.Content = lp;
                win2.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Whats Happen
In process Page is opened and closed automatic, in sequence he is going to next check, this case opening MainWindow.

I have to:
When Open the form, I need BackgroundWorker wait user close Win2 and after that keep doing your check

EDIT ========================================================================

I Tried:

```
private AutoResetEvent _workerCompleted = new AutoResetEvent(false);
setMensagemText(count++, "Verificando Banco de dados...", totalExecucao);
        VerificaDataBase();
        _workerCompleted.WaitOne();

        setMensagemText(count++, "Verificando Configurações Locais", totalExecucao);
        verificaConfiguracaoLocal();
        _workerCompleted.WaitOne();

private void verificaConfiguracaoLocal()
    {
        LocalBean localBean = new LocalBean();
        localBean.CarregaModel();

        verificaAbrirPage(localBean.Model.Id, typeof(LocalPage));

        if (LocalBean.ModelStatic.Id.Equals(0))
        {
            NotificacaoUtil.Error("Para o sistema carregar corretamente, é necessário ter uma configuração local. O sistema será finalizado!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }


    }

private void verificaAbrirPage(long id, Type page)
    {
        if (id.Equals(0))
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Page lp = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page);
                Window win2 = new Window();
                win2.Content = lp;
                win2.Closed += (s, a) =>
                {
                    _workerCompleted.Set();
                };
                win2.Show();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            _workerCompleted.Set();
        }
    }
```

but keep not working

Comment: Use a WaitOne semaphore to signal background worker when form is closed.

Comment: I would suggest not using BackgroundWorker, and instead, go with ReactiveExtensions and Observables. OnNext can be your progress. You can also use another Observable to signal the other way, from Page to you worker Observable. Also, observables as a whole can be awaited and it makes it all easier.

Comment: look about background, I Edit post, Krzysztop where Can I see examples ReactiveExtensions and Observables? cant found for c# wpf